# Kendo ui toolbar buttons tooltip text (title) change in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, tooltip

Kendo ui toolbar buttons tooltip text (title) change in angular.
I want to change Kendo ui toolbar buttons tooltip text (title) in angular for example…
change undo button tooltip text to different word etc in my angular component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you try setting a title like in the demo: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/toolbar/